# Java estructura en el @ResponseBody personalizada

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

Estoy haciendo un mapeo desde la base de datos con MyBatis en Java. Está es la forma en que lo estoy haciendo y todo está trabajando muy bien:

```
final static String GET_CONFIGURATION = "select c.codigo, c.simbolo, c.fecha, c.moneda"
            + " from pps.cuenta c"
            + " where c.cuenta_id=#{accountId}";

@Select(GET_ACCOUNT_CONFIGURATION)
    @Results(value = { @Result(property = "code", javaType = String.class, column = "codigo"),
        @Result(property = "symbol", javaType = String.class, column = "simbolo"),
        @Result(property = "date", javaType = String.class, column = "fecha"),
        @Result(property = "currency", javaType = String.class, column = "moneda")})
    public Account getAccountConfiguration(@Param("accountId") final Integer accountId);
```

Lo anterior es mapeado a un objeto `Account`:

```
public class Account {

    private String code;    
    private String symbol;  
    private String date;    
    private String currency;    

    /** Getter ans Setter */
    ...

}
```

En el controlador estoy usando el mapeador a través de un servicio, recibiendo un parámetro (`accountId`):

```
@RequestMapping(value = SecureApiResources.Account.URI_GET_ACCOUNTS_CONFIGURATION, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody AccountConfiguration getAccountConfiguration(@PathVariable(value = "accountId") Integer accountId) {   

            Account account = accountService.getAccountConfiguration(accountId);
            ...
            return account;
}
```

Entonces, cuando pruebo mi `endpoint` obtengo esta respuesta:

```
{
  "code": "COP",
  "symbol": "$"
  "date": "dd/MM/yyyy",
  "currency": "99.999,99"
}
```

Sin embargo necesito esta estructura:

```
{
  "currency": {
    "code": "COP",
    "symbol": "$"
  },
  "formats": {
    "date": "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "currency": "99.999,99"
  }
}
```

Puedo crear un objeto `configuration` que contenga otros dos `currency` y `formats`, pero esto representa que necesito crear estos objetos y asignarles los valores correspondientes. Ésta no parece ser la manera más correcta.

Comment: Quizás puedes resolver tu problema utilizando `ResponseBodyAdvice` (dado que utilizas Spring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza una instancia de [**`java.util.Map`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Es decir, para la estructura que necesitas, sería algo parecido a:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@RequestMapping(value = SecureApiResources.Account.URI_GET_ACCOUNTS_CONFIGURATION,
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAccountConfiguration(
        @PathVariable(value = "accountId") Integer accountId) {

    final Account account = accountService.getAccountConfiguration(accountId);

    ⋮

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {
        {
            put("currency", new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {
                {
                    put("code", account.getCode());
                    put("symbol", account.getSymbol());
                }
            });
            put("formats", new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {
                {
                    put("date", account.getDate());
                    put("currency", account.getCurrency());
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```